# hidden iframe issue with iphone safari

Tags: javascript, html

Safari iphone/ipad doesn't honor 0px for width and height on an iframe and puts a big one.

Has anyone seen that or found a fix other than setting display to none since 0px seems to work on all the browsers.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by zeroing out every parameter I could find:

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
el.setAttribute('id', 'yourFrameId');
el.height = 0;el.width = 0;
el.hspace="0";el.vspace="0";
el.marginheight="0";el.marginwidth="0";
el.frameBorder = "0";el.scrolling = "No";
```

or inline:

```
<iframe src="test.html" id="yourFrameId" width="0" marginwidth="0" height="0" marginheight="0" align="top" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">Browser not compatible. </iframe>
```

I also set display: none in the CSS.

That got it working for me on iOS.  Haven't tested on other mobile browsers, but if you have problems, some things you could try are setting position: absolute, top: -9999px, etc.